# resize map and add points to it using R

Tags: shapefile, r, esri-geodatabase, spatial-statistics, sp

I am working with spatial data [UK](http://census.edina.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/infuse_dist_lyr_2011_clipped.zip).

The map is plotted here. I want to resize the map and make it bigger and clear! 
[image: UK_map]

here is my code

LA <- readOGR(dsn =".", "infuse_dist_lyr_2011_clipped")

plot(LA)

Comment: As per the [Tour] would you be able to **edit** your question to focus it on just one of your questions and then research/ask the other separately, please?

Comment: What are you aiming to do with the output, exactly? Is this for a printed product, or on-screen display?

Answer (score 3):

The native plot window of R does not have zoom capability, but here are some options:

- resize your plot window
- only plot a section of the map by specifying `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to `plot()`
- write the map to a very large pdf, e.g. precede the `plot` command by `pdf("file.pdf", width=20, height=20)` and send this to a plotter
- write to the plot to pdf, load in a pdf viewer, and zoom there